# Progress bar based on image

Tags: swift, progress-bar

I need to create a progress bar based on image in Swift.
I have 2 vector images in pdf with next preferences:
[image]
[image]

What I tried:
1) Place background image (UIViewImage)
2) Put on top full image (UIViewImage)
3) Crop full image to 50% (image!.cgImage!.cropping(to:cropZone))

I expected to see a part of the background image, like this:
[image]

But I see a big part of full image:
[image]

Here is my test code:

```
    let cropZone = CGRect(x:30,y:375-96,width:70,height:184)
    let cutImageRef: CGImage = self.coolantFull.image!.cgImage!.cropping(to:cropZone)!
    self.coolantFull.image! = UIImage(cgImage: cutImageRef)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your top Image View is set to one of `.fill`, `.aspectFit`, or `.aspectFill` for a content scaling mode. For this scenario, you'll want to make sure you're using `.topLeft` to ensure the content doesn't scale or shift around as the masking progresses.

Comment: I use vector pdf, I think it is always need to scale. If I set .topLeft I see a big image, that not fit on screen.

Comment: Ahh...I see. Honestly, I’d recommend you rasterize the PDF at the size you need it and import it as PNGs rather than importing a gigantic vector image and letting the Image View scale it down for you.

Comment: I make universal apps for iphone and ipad. It would be great to use vector graphics instead create png for all resolutions.

Comment: I will use PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I written extension for UIImageView which create a new image based on percentages and resizes itself. Filling goes from bottom to top. Rasterized pdf looks bad, so now I use png @1, @2, @3.

```
extension UIImageView {
func progress(to _percent: CGFloat, image: UIImage) {
    // restore original image and size in UIImageView
    self.image! = image
    self.frame.size = image.size
    // if less then 0, return 0
    var percent = _percent <= 0 ? 1 : _percent
    // if more then 100, return 100
    percent = percent > 100 ? 100 : percent
    let size = CGSize(width: self.frame.size.width, height: self.frame.size.height/100*percent)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, self.image!.scale)
    self.image!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0,
                                y: -self.frame.size.height+size.height,
                                width: self.image!.size.width,
                                height: self.image!.size.height))

    let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    self.frame = CGRect(x: self.frame.origin.x,
                        y: self.frame.height-self.frame.height/100*percent,
                        width: self.frame.width,
                        height: self.frame.height/100*percent)
    self.image! = croppedImage
}
```

How to use:

```
@IBOutlet weak var coolantProgress: UIImageView!

let coolantEmptyImage = UIImage.init(named: "coolantFull")
coolantProgress.progress(to: 25, image: coolantEmptyImage!)
```

[image]